# From $\lim_{x\to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$ to $f=g$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that if $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are periodic and $\lim_{x\to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$,
>   then $f=g$

**My attempt**

Let $T_1$, $T_2>0$ be periods of $f$ and $g$ repectively.

If $T_1/T_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, the conclusion is trivial.

If $T_1/T_2 \in  \mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q}$, WLOG we assume that $T_2=1$.

Put $A_n=\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|>\frac{1}{n}\}$. Then $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\{x:f(x)-g(x)\ne0\}$.

I want to show that $\{x:f(x)-g(x)\ne0\}$ is uncountable so that there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_k$ is uncountable and hence the contradiction is deduced.

But I got stuck on that. Maybe it relates to the property of $\{n\alpha\}$. Any hints? Thanks in advance!